# How to aggregate data for lagging months only

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag

I've run into a bit of a problem cleansing our order data.

The dataset includes duplicate colour codes (orders) over the years, and I need to sum the data only if it's in the same month, or rolled over from the previous month.

I have tried this query, which returns the below table.

```
;WITH CTE_Rollovers AS
    (
        SELECT 
            CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF (month, 0, OrderDate), 0) AS DATE) AS OrderDate, 
            ColourCode, 
            RequiredTO, 
            DispatchedTO,
            CASE WHEN COALESCE(LAG(OrderDate, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ColourCode ORDER BY OrderDate),'') != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsRollover
          FROM VW_QORDER_HIS_OrderDetail (NOLOCK)
            WHERE 
                OrderIsActive = 1 AND
                IsCurrent = 1 AND
                SpecMaterialType = 'HC Product' AND 
                Vessel = 'Port Stock' AND 
                ColourCode != 'Unknown'
    )
        SELECT * FROM CTE_Rollovers 
            WHERE IsRollover = 1 AND ColourCode = 'Aqua Preto' ORDER BY ColourCode
```

Per below example, I need to aggregate only the ones in bold

| OrderDate | ColourCode | RequiredTO | DispatchedTO | IsRollover |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-12-01 | Aqua Preto | 4000.000 | 3566.650 | 1 |
| **2015-06-01** | **Aqua Preto** | **14250.000** | **4613.350** | **1** |
| **2015-07-01** | **Aqua Preto** | **9690.720** | **9690.720** | **1** |
| 2016-01-01 | Aqua Preto | 9991.550 | 9991.550 | 1 |
| **2016-12-01** | **Aqua Preto** | **7000.000** | **4197.190** | **1** |
| **2016-12-01** | **Aqua Preto** | **2800.000** | **2833.920** | **1** |
| 2017-03-01 | Aqua Preto | 17000.000 | 14860.520 | 1 |

Desired result:

| OrderDate | ColourCode | RequiredTO | DispatchedTO | IsRollover |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-12-01 | Aqua Preto | 4000.000 | 3566.650 | 1 |
| **2015-06-01** | **Aqua Preto** | **23940.72** | **14304.07** | **1** |
| 2016-01-01 | Aqua Preto | 9991.550 | 9991.550 | 1 |
| **2016-12-01** | **Aqua Preto** | **9800.000** | **4197.190** | **1** |
| 2017-03-01 | Aqua Preto | 17000.000 | 14860.520 | 1 |

Comment: Use GROUP BY Statement in OrderDate for learn more about GROUP BY Statement here is the link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Why is `DispatchedTO` equal to `SUM` of input values in the second row, but in fourth row it is not (it is equal to first or `MAX` value)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nifty solution using [dense_rank](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) in order to group consecutive months.

```
with t as (
          select dense_rank() over (order by year(OrderDate),month(OrderDate)) as rank
                ,OrderDate
                ,ColourCode
                ,RequiredTO
                ,DispatchedTO
                ,IsRollover
          from   VW_QORDER_HIS_OrderDetail
          )
 
select  min(OrderDate)    as OrderDate
       ,min(ColourCode)   as ColourCode
       ,sum(RequiredTO)   as RequiredTO
       ,sum(DispatchedTO) as DispatchedTO
       ,min(IsRollover)   as IsRollover
from    t
group by rank - (year(OrderDate)*12+month(OrderDate))
order by OrderDate
```

| OrderDate | ColourCode | RequiredTO | DispatchedTO | IsRollover |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-12-01 | Aqua Preto | 4000 | 3566.65 | 1 |
| 2015-06-01 | Aqua Preto | 23940.72 | 14304.07 | 1 |
| 2016-01-01 | Aqua Preto | 9991.55 | 9991.55 | 1 |
| 2016-12-01 | Aqua Preto | 9800 | 7031.11 | 1 |
| 2017-03-01 | Aqua Preto | 17000 | 14860.52 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=015602f84a55d86cacfea53197fbebbe&hide=1)